# Update que no modifica la tabla

Tags: php, mysqli

[image: Pagina de donde viene el idusr=id]
[image: Pagina para cambiar el codigo]

**NUEVO CODIGO**

MUY COMENTADO para explicar donde funciona y donde no!

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
// Include config file
require_once '990conn.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link href="css/sbg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once '990conn.php';
//OBTENGO el 98idusr (alias id) que me manda la pagina anterior es número PERFECTO
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);
        echo $id; //muest5ro el id
//A quien le voy a cambiar el grupo, obvio al dueño del id = $id = 98idusr PERFECTO
$sql098a="select * from $t98 WHERE 98idusr = '$id'";
if($result098a = $mysqli->query($sql098a)){
    if($result098a->num_rows == 1){
        while($row098a = $result098a->fetch_array()){
//muestro el nombre del usuario al que le voy a cambiar el grupo PERFECTO
                echo "<td><strong>" . $row098a['98nomb'] . "</strong></td>"; 
        }
        // Free result set POR LAS DUDAS LO COMENTE, NO VAYA A CERRAR NADA
//        $result098a->free();
    } else{
        echo "No hay coincidencia en la búsqueda.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql098a. " . $mysqli->error;
}
    }
?>  
<table width="280" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><form action="098usuarios.php" method="post" target="_self" class="row" title="f098">
<!-- Selecciono el grupo dinamicamente de la tabla $t98g = 98gr que solo contiene dos columnas idgr (numérica) y gr (nombre del grupo) -->
<tr><td><select name="grupo" required  id="grupo" form="f098" title="grupo" ><option value="">Seleccione nuevo grupo</option>
<?php $sql098b="select idgr, gr from $t98g"; //$t98g es el alias de la tabla 98gr
$r098b=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql098b); 
while($rw098b=mysqli_fetch_array($r098b)) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rw098b['idgr']; ?>"><?php echo $rw098b['gr']; ?></option><?php }?>
</select></td></tr>
<tr>
<!-- Botón submit que DEBERIA cambiar el grupo NO PARECE QUE FUNCIONARA, no dice error ni cambia la pagina -->
<td><input name="bt-098" type="submit" class="btn-primary" id="bt-098" form="f098" formaction="098usuarios.php" formmethod="POST" title="bt-098" value="CAMBIAR GRUPO"></td>
<!-- Por las dudas verifico que el id = 98idusr sigue firme como rulo de estatua en el html-->
<input  name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</tr></form></tbody></table>
<?php
// verificar que el boton SUBMIT fue presionado Y PARECE QUE NO, PORQUE NO CAMBIA EL GRUPO
if(isset($_POST['bt-098']))
{
// Archivo de conexion mysqli sale de aqui
require_once '990conn.php';
// seleccionar la variable que se va a actualizar grupo = 98grupo también un número definida en la selecion 
$grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
$sql098 = "UPDATE $t98 SET 98grupo = '$grupo' WHERE 98idusr='$id'"; //$t98 es el alias de la tabla 98usr
if($mysqli->query($sql098) === true){
    echo "El grupo fue cambiado.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: No es posible ejecutar $sql098. " . $mysqli->error;
}
}
// Close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Buenas tardes, buen domingo! Despues de todos los retos de Cedano porque no uso consultas preparadas o parametrizadas! Armé un código que presuntamente lo haría feliz, lleno de esas cosillas.

Pero no anda t1 tablas 98usr (campos varios sólo me interesan 98idusr, 98nomb, 98grupo # [este es el que quiero actualizar]) 98gr (sólo contiene idgr # y gr txt porque la gente no memoriza pavadas y yo no quiero andar deambulando mucho con numeritos)

El codigo trae un id de otra pagina que quedó bonitica y al fin logré que envíe sólo el id = 98idusr  hasta aquí todo bien.

Va código con toda la elegancia que me caracteriza (no critiquen mucho)PROBLEMA: NO CARGA EN LA tabla 98idusr el nuevo idgr.

Soy toda anteojitos. Gracias!
**CODIGO ANTERIOR**

```
// Include config file
require_once '990conn.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$grupo = "";
$grupo_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["98idusr"]) && !empty($_POST["98idusr"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["98idusr"];

    // Validate grupo
    $input_grupo = trim($_POST["98grupo"]);
    if(empty($input_grupo)){
        $grupo_err = "Elija un grupo.";     
    } elseif(!ctype_digit($input_grupo)){
        $grupo_err = 'Please enter a positive integer value.';
    } else{
        $grupo = $input_grupo;
    }
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($grupo_err)){
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql098 = "UPDATE 98usr SET 98grupo=['idgr'] WHERE 98idusr=?";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql098)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_grupo, $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_grupo = $grupo;
            $param_id = $id;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: 098usuarios.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);

        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql098b = "SELECT * FROM 98usr WHERE 98idusr = ?";
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql098b)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $id;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $result098b = $stmt->get_result();

                if($result098b->num_rows == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                    contains only one row, we don't need to use while l<em>oo</em>p */
                    $row098b = $result098b->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $name = $row098b["98nomb"];
 //                   $grupo = $row098b["98grupo"];
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: 098error.php");
                    exit();
                }

            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: 098error.php");
        exit();
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>xxxxxxx</title>
    <link href="css/sbg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 280px;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            text-align: center;
            align-self: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class=page-header-280><table width="280" heigth="28" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#4C89C0" class="copete-bl-md"><tbody><tr>
    <td align="center">Cambiar grupo</td></tr></tbody></table>
    <div class="wrapper"  width= "280">
        <div class="container-fluid" width= 280 >
            <div class="row" widht= 280 >
                    <p>Por favor seleccione el nuevo grupo</p> 
                    <p>y presione el boton para actualizar los datos.</p>
                    <p> </p>
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group"  <?php echo (!empty($name_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Nombre  </label>
                            <strong><?php echo $name; ?></strong>
                        </div>
                    <div class="form-group" <?php echo (!empty($grupo_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <td><select name="grupo" required id="grupo" form="f098u" title="grupo" ><option value="">Elija el nuevo grupo</option>
<?php $sql098c="select idgr, gr from 98gr"; 
$r098c=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql098c); 
while($rw098c=mysqli_fetch_array($r098c)) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rw098c['idgr']; ?>"><?php echo $rw098c['gr']; ?></option><?php }?>
    </select></td>
                       <span class="help-block"><?php echo $grupo_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Actualizar">... 
                    <a href="098usuarios.php" class="btn-default">Cancel</a></p>
                    </form>
<?php
// Close statement
$stmt->close();

// Close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me alegra de que hayas decidido dar seguridad a tu código. Ahora bien, hay algo raro aquí: `$sql098 = "UPDATE 98usr SET 98grupo=['idgr'] WHERE 98idusr=?"`  **¿A qué quieres igualar la columna `98grupo` realmente?** Debes saber que el `$stmt->bind_param("i", $param_grupo, $param_id);` debe recibir tantos tipos de datos y valores como signos de `?` tengas en la consulta sql. Aquí tienes un sólo tipo de dato `i` y luego dos valores `$param_grupo` y `$param_id`, mientras que en la consulta tienes un sólo `?`. Es posible que a tu consulta le falte un `?`.

Comment: ahí ['idgr'] presumo que lo toma de la sql098c y es el campo que quiero agregar que también es # en cambio el Where se refiere al id que viene de la página anterior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE 30-10-2017

Hice una prueba de concepto de tu código. Hice funcionar la primera parte, la del `UPDATE`.

No funcionaba por dos motivos, aparte de **todo** lo que ya te he dicho en las diferentes actualizaciones de esta respuesta.

### Primer motivo nuevo de error

Una extraña manipulación de variables en este bloque del código:

```
    // Validate grupo
    $input_grupo = trim($_POST["98grupo"]);
    if(empty($input_grupo)){
        $grupo_err = "Elija un grupo.";
    } elseif(!ctype_digit($input_grupo)){
        $grupo_err = 'Please enter a positive integer value.';
    } else{
        $grupo = $input_grupo;
    }
```

En mi prueba, `$grupo` terminaba siendo igual al valor `id`, el que usas como filtro del `WHERE` de la consulta. No puedo darte más detalles sobre esto porque los valores que recoges en el POST yo los sustituí por valores escritos a mano.

### Segundo motivo nuevo de error

**Este es el error más gordo.**

Al hacer una operación de igualdad **posterior** al `bind` de las variables pasadas en el mismo... no sabemos lo que estabas pasando, quizá no pasabas nada...o quien sabe lo que pasabas.

Me refiero a esto:

```
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql098)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_grupo, $param_id);

        // Set parameters
        $param_grupo = $grupo;
        $param_id = $id;
```

**Solución:**

Pasar ambas variables arriba, antes del `bind`, para que así  el `bind` pase los valores reales:

```
        // Set parameters
        $param_grupo = $grupo;
        $param_id = $id;

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql098)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_grupo, $param_id);
```

Con estas dos correcciones el `UPDATE` debería funcionar.

[Aquí te dejo el código de prueba](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zjny-n6cr). Debes pulsar **<kbd>Run-F9</kbd>** para probarlo. Lo puedes probar, cambiando el valor de esta línea :

```
$grupo = "Los Miserables";  /*CAMBIAR ESTE VALOR PARA PROBAR*/
```

por otro valor.

---

### Estas son respuestas anteriores también válidas parcialmente

Hay al menos dos errores en tu código:

#### Primer error

<strike>`$sql098 = "UPDATE 98usr SET 98grupo=['idgr'] WHERE 98idusr=?";`</strike>

Imagino que quieres igualar la columna 98grupo a un valor almacenado en una variable. Entonces, debes colocar también ahí un signo de `?`:

```
    $sql098 = "UPDATE 98usr SET 98grupo=? WHERE 98idusr=?";
```

#### Segundo error

<s>`$stmt->bind_param("i", $param_grupo, $param_id);`</s>

Debes tener cuidado al hacer el binding. Debes observar muy esctrictamente las siguientes normas:

1. Debes pasar tantos valores como signos de `?` tengas en la consulta. Si aquí tienes dos, debes hacer binding de dos valores.
2. Debes pasarlos en el orden en que aparecen los signos de `?` en la consulta.
3. Evidentemente, las variables que pasas deben existir.
4. Las letras después del paréntesis de apertura, indican el tipo de dato de cada columna en la base de datos: `i` para enteros, `s` para string, etc.

Tomando en cuenta esto, corregimos el binding:

Si `$param_grupo` no es numérico en la base de datos:

```
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $param_grupo, $param_id);
```

En cambio, si `$param_grupo` es numérico en la base de datos:

```
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $param_grupo, $param_id);
```

Si así no funciona, es porque tienes error en otra parte del código.

#### Tercer error

No cierres la conexión si vas a seguir usándola, por ejemplo aquí:

```
    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close(); //LA CERRASTE
} else{
// Check existence of id parameter before processing further
if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
    // Get URL parameter
    $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);

    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql098b = "SELECT * FROM 98usr WHERE 98idusr = ?";
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql098b)){  //PERO CERRASTE $mysqli ¿como pretendes usarla aquí?
```

---

### UPDATE

Viendo que había más errores en el código, he escrito esta versión del código controlado. Ahora, si falla, te dirá dónde y por qué falla.

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

// Include config file
require_once '990conn.php';

if($mysqli){

    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $grupo = "";
    $grupo_err = "";

    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if(isset($_POST["98idusr"]) && !empty($_POST["98idusr"])){
        // Get hidden input value
        $id = $_POST["98idusr"];

        // Validate grupo
        $input_grupo = trim($_POST["98grupo"]);
        if(empty($input_grupo)){
            $grupo_err = "Elija un grupo.";
        } elseif(!ctype_digit($input_grupo)){
            $grupo_err = 'Please enter a positive integer value.';
        } else{
            $grupo = $input_grupo;
        }
        // Check input errors before inserting in database
        if(empty($grupo_err)){

            // Prepare an insert statement
            $sql098 = "UPDATE 98usr SET 98grupo=? WHERE 98idusr=?";

            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql098)){

                // Set parameters
                $param_grupo = $grupo;
                $param_id = $id;

                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                $stmt->bind_param("ii", $param_grupo, $param_id);


                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    printf("%d Filas actualizadas.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

                    // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                    header("location: 098usuarios.php");
                    exit();
                } else{
                    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }

                // Close statement
                $stmt->close();

            }else{

                echo "Error en la consulta.";

            }


        }else{

            echo "No se cumplió nada de lo que evaluaste de la variable group_err";

        }

    } else {
        // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
        if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
            // Get URL parameter
            $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);

            // Prepare a select statement
            $sql098b = "SELECT * FROM 98usr WHERE 98idusr = ?";
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql098b)){

                // Set parameters
                $param_id = $id;

                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_id);


                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $result098b = $stmt->get_result();

                    if($result098b->num_rows == 1){
                        /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                    contains only one row, we don't need to use while l<em>oo</em>p */
                        $row098b = $result098b->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                        // Retrieve individual field value
                        $name = $row098b["98nomb"];
                        //                   $grupo = $row098b["98grupo"];
                    } else{
                        // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                        header("location: 098error.php");
                        exit();
                    }

                } else{
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }
        }  else{
            // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
            header("location: 098error.php");
            exit();
        }
    }

}else{

    echo "La conexión es nula";
}

?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68018/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-update-que-no-modifica-la-tabla).

Comment: @Cedano, estoy en el chat,